# Как проверить выделен ли объект в treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно проверить выделен ли какой-нибудь объект в treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаете список выделенных объектов, потом проверяете, находится ли нужный объект среди них:

```
items = treeview.selection()
if 'someitem' in items:
    ...
```